# How can I create executable jars with embedded tomcat 9?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat9

Has anyone tried the plugin to build an executable war/jar using Tomcat 9?

I attempted to do so however ran into:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.setConfig(Ljava/lang/String;)V
>   at org.apache.tomcat.maven.runner.Tomcat7Runner.run(Tomcat7Runner.java:240)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.maven.runner.Tomcat7RunnerCli.main(Tomcat7RunnerCli.java:204)
> ```

I looked at the source and changed Catalina.setConfig() to Catalina.setConfigFile() based on docs [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Catalina.html#setConfigFile(java.lang.String)).  After doing so the .extract dir is just empty:

> use extractDirectory:.extract populateWebAppWarPerContext
>   warValue:ROOT.war|ROOT populateWebAppWarPerContext
>   contextValue/warFileName:ROOT/ROOT.war webappWarPerContext entry
>   key/value: ROOT/ROOT.war expand to file:.extract/webapps/ROOT.war
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: FATAL: impossible to
>   create directories:.extract/webapps   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.runner.Tomcat7Runner.extract(Tomcat7Runner.java:586)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.runner.Tomcat7Runner.run(Tomcat7Runner.java:204)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.maven.runner.Tomcat7RunnerCli.main(Tomcat7RunnerCli.java:204)

.... although there is a ROOT.war, server.xml, web.xml in the *-exec-war.jar.

Is there a better way to be creating exec-jars with embedded tomcat 9?

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a solution it was fairly straight forward to checkout the code for the plugin and make a few changes to get this to work.  Namely:
Update POM to change the depends to Tomcat 9
Fix compile errors which generally stem from deprecated methods.  The lookup on these methods can be found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/deprecated-list.html).  For example:

```
-                container.setConfig( serverXml.getAbsolutePath() );
+                container.setConfigFile( serverXml.getAbsolutePath() );
```

... and ...

```
-            staticContext.addServletMapping( "/", "staticContent" );
+            staticContext.addServletMappingDecoded( "/", "staticContent" );
```

There are a few others but generally not difficult to resolve.  After doing so I updated my app's pom to use the modified version and was able to generate a Tomcat 9 exec jar.

I would love to hear what others are doing here.  I know some are programmatically initializing Tomcat via a `new Tomcat()` instance however curious what other solutions exist ready made.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For future searchs, one solution is to use the DirResourceSet or JarResourceSet.

```
    String webAppMount = "/WEB-INF/classes";
    WebResourceSet webResourceSet;
    if (!isJar()) {
        webResourceSet = new DirResourceSet(webResourceRoot, webAppMount, getResourceFromFs(), "/");
    } else {
        webResourceSet = new JarResourceSet(webResourceRoot, webAppMount, getResourceFromJarFile(), "/");
    }
    webResourceRoot.addJarResources(webResourceSet);
    context.setResources(webResourceRoot);


public static boolean isJar() {
    URL resource = Main.class.getResource("/");
    return resource == null;
}

public static String getResourceFromJarFile() {
    File jarFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    return jarFile.getAbsolutePath();
}

public static String getResourceFromFs() {
    URL resource = Main.class.getResource("/");
    return resource.getFile();
}
```

When add the webapp, use root path "/" for docBase:

```
tomcat.addWebapp("", "/")
```

Credits for:
https://nkonev.name/post/101