# convert a war project to jar project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, axis

I want convert this war project https://github.com/mpuening/learn-webservices-jaxrpc into a jar project.

I have tried to set in the file pom.xml the jar package but trying to execute the application I'll get the following error
ERROR o.a.a.c.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet[EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet.java:162] - Unable to find config file. Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd
ERROR o.a.a.c.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet[EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet.java:176] - Problem with servlet engine /WEB-INF directory

WARN o.a.a.c.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet[EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet.java:184] - Unable to load/create servlet engine config file, attempting internal default (from jar).
WARN o.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils[JavaUtils.java:1308] - Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.

and inside the response I'll get a 500 error response with following body

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
soapenv:Body
soapenv:Fault
ns1:Server.NoService
The AXIS engine could not find a target service to invoke! targetService is WEBPanelServices

<ns2:hostname xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">PC01A</ns2:hostname>

</soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

this happens because setting jar packaging the src/main/webapp directory is ignored and server-config.wsdd is not included in the resulting jar file.

I have googled and found the following threads
[How can I create executable jars with embedded tomcat 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123351/how-can-i-create-executable-jars-with-embedded-tomcat-9)

but where should I add that line of code in the project? In the class "WebServiceServerConfig" annotated with "@Configuration" ? And what should I add?

Hope that somebody help me

I have tried the jar package but doesn't work.

Comment: did you notice that the question you linked is about a completely different problem in a scenario that is similar to yours? I looks as "they" had the executable JAR already built...

Comment: And I can't provide a full solution as I didn't solve this problem myself yet, but maybe this link helps you a bit more: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-run-maven-vs-executable-jar